# Reflection fails to get assembly types in Citrix

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, citrix

I have a WPF app running over Citrix and in one ViewModel, I load types and list them in a drop down. This works perfectly well when running locally but fails when running over Citrix. Please explain what I'm doing wrong.

```
//Get assembly
 var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
//Get all report objects from assembly with a display name attribute defined
//This is what fails on Citrix
var rep = asm.GetTypes().Where(x => (typeof(Telerik.Reporting.Report)).IsAssignableFrom(x) && x.IsDefined(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute), true)).ToList();
```

Comment: Does it generate an error? What error? Or does it just not get any reports?

Comment: There's an exception that is caught but because of the way they have the security set up on the Citrix box, I haven't been able to actually log it out.

Comment: Well, until you find out you're pretty much out of luck. Can't you write it a database (if you're using in the app), or the event log?

Comment: I do write to the event log... but they've got that locked down too somehow. It's very frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the deployment wasn't copying over one of the libraries... GOt it fixed.